# Firebase v9 Payment Intent

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments

I am building this app And I needed to setup this payment Intent with Stripe and Firebase.. but due to some issues i am confused between firebase v8 and v9 statement.. hence need help

Can someone convert this v8 code into v9 firebase

```
db.collection("users")
      .doc(user?.uid)
      .collection("orders")
      .doc(paymentIntent.id)
      .set({
        basket: basket,
        amount: paymentIntent.amount,
        created: paymentIntent.created,
      });
```

---

```
I have tried these approaches but nothing seems to work
   .then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
    //paymentIntent = payment Confirmation
         console.log(user);
    // db.collection("users")
    //   .doc(user?.uid)
    //   .collection("orders")
    //   .doc(paymentIntent.id)
    //   .set({
    //     basket: basket,
    //     amount: paymentIntent.amount,
    //     created: paymentIntent.created,
    //   });
    const docRef = collection(db, "users");
    const docRefId = getDoc(docRef);
    const paymentRef = collection(docRefId, "orders");
    setDoc(doc(paymentRef, paymentIntent.id), {
      basket: basket,
      amount: paymentIntent.amount,
      created: paymentIntent.created,
    });
```

also tried this one...

```
const docRef = doc(collection(db, "users", user?.uid));
 const newRef = doc(collection(docRef, "orders", 
 paymentIntent?.id));
 setDoc(newRef, {
      basket: basket,
      amount: paymentIntent.amount,
      created: paymentIntent.created,
 });
```

Comment: The Firebase documentation has pretty good example of the v8 and v9 API side by side, so I recommend starting [there](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document). If you've tried the conversion already and got stuck, edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show us exactly where you got stuck please.

Comment: Exactly, you need to show that you have at least tried looking at the API documentation and have got stuck on a specific point. "Please do this for me" without showing that you have put in some effort will get you lots of downvotes and similar comments. Please see the guidelines on [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am really new to stackoverflow, and I always fix my bugs by myself... but this one really took a lot from me....

Comment: I dont know how to link but let me tell what exactly i want to do in this question... i want to.... I have a collection as users... I want to access it ... with {user?.id} then from there I want to query another collection inside of it... namely "orders" and then from orders I want to set PaymentIntent

Comment: I have read the documentation but it does give an overview into query nested collection... going from one collection into another